# Why I can't update update my JavaScript object properties value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problem with updating my App object properties value! I'm trying to update the 'visible' property from false to true whenever I'm calling methods within my App object!

Now I can't figure out why I can't update the values!!! Could somebody please help me?

Here is the code;

```
var app = app || {};

app.layout = {

    // SIDEBAR
    'sidebar': function(a) {
        var options = {
            'settings': {
                'object': $('.sidebar-left'),
                'visible': false,
                'type': 'wide'
            },
            'open': function() {
                if(options.isActive() === false) {
                    options.settings.visible = true;
                    options.settings.object.addClass('active');
                }
            },
            'close': function() {
                if(options.isActive() === true) {
                    options.settings.visible = false;
                    options.settings.object.removeClass('active');

                }
            },
            'isActive': function() {
                if(options.settings.visible === true) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return options[a];
    }

    // HEADER
    // CONTENT
    // FOOTER
}
```

The idea behind this little App API is that I don't need to go and manually check whether a container is visible and change the UI manually, I could just call the app.layout methods and that should do the job...

As you can see, I'm trying to update the 'visible' property value when the two methods of `app.layout.sidebar('open')();` and `app.layout.sidebar('close')();` are called!

Thank you

---

Here is the updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/Farzad/ndb1490v/3/

Hope it helps those that are looking to integrate this to their app, as it makes it really easy to keep track of your UI without needing you to manually check every time...

However if anybody knows any better approach then make an update to the jsFiddle version and link back in the comments section :)

Thank you guys, specially those who being helpful
Cheers

Comment: Are you getting some error in console?

Comment: Every time you call `app.layout.sidebar()` you're creating a brand new "options" object, in which the "visible" property is initialized to `false`.

Comment: Your `options`object is redefined each time you call the `sidebar`function ; hence you reset the values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript may help

Comment: Side note: You're doing a lot of `===` comparisons with booleans. That's almost never necessary. For instance, unless you're going to store somethign other than a boolean in `options.settings.visible`, then your entire `isActive` could more readably be written: `isActive: function() { return options.settings.visible; }`. Similarly, since `isActive` only ever returns `true` or `false`, you don't need `if(options.isActive() === true)`, just use `if(options.isActive())` Similarly, `if(options.isActive() === false)` becomes `if(!options.isActive())`.

Comment: No, no error in console... I'm also able to change the value in the console, but nothing changes!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow, thanks for the explanation, I'll give that a go... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is *recreating* the options object every time `sidebar` is called, with `false` as the hardcoded value of `visible`:

```
app.layout = {

    // SIDEBAR
    'sidebar': function(a) {
        var options = {
            'settings': {
                'object': $('.sidebar-left'),
                'visible': false,                 // <=== Note
                'type': 'wide'
            },
            // ...
        return options[a];
    }
}
```

So **any** call you make like this:

```
app.layout.sidebar('open')();
```

...will always see `options.settings.visible` as `false`.

I can't see any reason for the complexity in your `layout` object, and so can't really recommend an appropriate change, other than to make sure `options` is not recreated each time.

If you're happy to use this kind of call instead:

```
app.layout.sidebar.open();
```

...then you can make things much less complicated:

```
var app = app || {};

app.layout = (function() {
    var options = {
        'settings': {
            'object': $('.sidebar-left'),
            'visible': false,
            'type': 'wide'
        }
    };
    return {
        sidebar: {
            'open': function() {
                if(options.isActive() === false) {
                    options.settings.visible = true;
                    options.settings.object.addClass('active');
                }
            },
            'close': function() {
                if(options.isActive() === true) {
                    options.settings.visible = false;
                    options.settings.object.removeClass('active');

                }
            },
            'isActive': function() {
                if(options.settings.visible === true) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // HEADER, e.g.
        ,
        header: {
            // ...
        }
        // CONTENT
        // FOOTER
    };
})();
```

Note that you need to make sure that code runs **after** the `.sidebar-left` element exists.

---

Side note: The quotes you've used in the `options` object property keys are all optional, you could just leave them off:

```
var options = {
    settings: {
        object: $('.sidebar-left'),
        visible: false,
        type: 'wide'
    }
};
```

Same goes for the ones defining `sidebar`. The only time you need quotes around property names in JavaScript is if the name is not a invalid *IdentifierName* (for instance, has spaces in it, or starts with a digit but isn't a number).

Comment: Yes, absolutely... thank you so much :) Very helpful, massive +1

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle version, http://jsfiddle.net/Farzad/ndb1490v/3/, one thing that I don't love about it yet is that I'm repeating myself for sidebarLeft and sidebarRight, they are both the same but with different classes... now my question is that can I somehow make this better without repeating my codes... thanks

Comment: @FarzadCyrus: That's a different question, I suggest posting it. :-) Put the example *in* the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` button), say you're not happy about how you've had to repeat things, and ask how not to repeat yourself.